# Finding the Fourier-Bessel Series For $f(x) = x$, $0 < x < 2$, With Respect to the Orthogonal Set $\{ J_1 (k_n(x)) \}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, orthogonality, bessel-functions

I am trying to find the Fourier-Bessel series for $f(x) = x$, $0 < x < 2$, with respect to the orthogonal set $\{ J_1 (k_n(x)) \}$, where $k_n$ is the $n^{th}$ positive root of the equation $J_1(2k) = 0$.

I am told that

$$\int_0^c x [J_\alpha (k_n(x)]^2 \ dx = \dfrac{c^2}{2} [J_{\alpha + 1}(k_n c)]^2,$$

where $k_n$ is a root of $J_{\alpha}(kc) = 0$.

I am also told that

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} [x^{\alpha} J_{\alpha}(x)] = x^{\alpha} J_{\alpha - 1}(x)$$

---

**What I Know About Fourier-Bessel Series:**

For any fixed $m$, the functions

$$\left\{ J_m \left( \dfrac{\mu_n^{(m)}x}{a} \right) \right\}_{n = 1}^\infty$$

are orthogonal w.r.t. the weight function $w(x) = x$ on $0 < x < a$. Here, $\mu_n^{(m)}$ is the $n^{th}$ zero of $J_m(\mu)$.

The Fourier-Bessel series for a function $f(x)$ defined on $(0, a)$ is

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty c_n J_m \left( \dfrac{\mu_n^{(m)}x}{a} \right)$$

---

I have absolutely no experience with Fourier-Bessel series or Bessel functions in general.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no $k_n(x)$, $k_n$ depends only on $n$. For convenience, let's normalize the basis. Let
$$e_n(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2 \,J_2(2 k_n)} J_1(k_n x), \\
J_1(2 k_n) = 0, \;n \in \mathbb N.$$
Then, with the inner product defined as
$$(f, g) = \int_0^2 x f(x) g(x) dx,$$
${e_n}$ form an orthonormal basis, $(e_m, e_n) = \delta_{mn}$. The expansion of $f$ in this basis has the form
$$\sum_n (f, e_n) e_n.$$
To compute the coefficients $(f, e_n)$ for $f(x) = x$, we use the fact that
$$\int x^2 J_1(a x) dx = \frac {x^2 J_2(a x)} a,$$
from which
$$(f, e_n) = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2 \,J_2(2 k_n)}
 \int_0^2 x^2 J_1(k_n x) dx =
\frac {2 \sqrt 2} {k_n}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you orthonormalisation the basis and get $e_n(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2 \,J_2(2 k_n)} J_1(k_n x)$?

Comment: This is the first identity in your post with $\alpha = 1, c = 2$, we have
$$(J_1(k_n x), J_1(k_n x)) =
\int_0^2 x J_1^2(k_n x) dx = 2 J_2^2(2 k_n), \\
\left( \frac {J_1(k_n x)} {\sqrt 2 \,J_2(2 k_n)},
 \frac {J_1(k_n x)} {\sqrt 2 \,J_2(2 k_n)} \right) = 1.$$